# inheriting vectors and initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

Am trying to inherit a class from a C++ vector and initialize it at the constructor. How do I do it? For example:

```
class Dataset:public std::vector<float>{
    public:
            Dataset(vector<float> val):*baseclass*(val){}
            // bruteforce way. // Dataset(vector<float> val){//for every val[i] call push_back(val[i]);}
```

ofcourse there's nothing as *baseclass*, what I mean by the above statement is I want to initialize the vector's data with val. how do I do it without push_back ing every element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't derive from `std::vector<>`. This class was never meant to be derived from. Use an instance of the class as a member instead:

```
struct Owns {
    Owns() : the_vector_(42, 128) { }

private:
    std::vector<float> the_vector_;
};
```

Comment: Deriving using private inheritance is actually a neat thing.

Comment: Not so much, unless you need access to the base class' protected members. That's Never(tm) the case with `std::vector`.

Comment: @user519770 if you want the vector's interface you're really going to have to write it on your own. I mean, write the interface, and wherever you see fit forward the calls to the member vector instance. See for example how `std::stack` behaves in your compiler's standard headers. That too is is a container adapter.

Comment: yep.. got it.. i just looked at stl_stack.h and it makes sense. thanks wilhelmtell

Answer (score 4):

You could write :

```
Dataset(const vector<float> &val): std::vector<float>(val) {}
```

but in the end, you really shouldn't inherit publicly from `std::vector`. There are multiple hints which show that `std::vector` is just not meant to be derived :

- No virtual destructor
- No protected members
- No virtual functions

You can't prevent anyone from treating your `Dataset` object as a `std::vector<float>`, because public inheritance means that `Dataset` **is a** `std::vector<float>`, and this will fail miserably if someone attempts to delete a `Database` object through a `std::vector<float>` pointer.

If you want to *reuse* `std::vector`, either use a private `std::vector` member, or inherit privately and expose what should be through `using` declarations.

Comment: I want to have operations such as push_back, pop_back, and iterators on my dataset thats the reason I am inheriting. what alternative do u suggest?

Comment: @user519770: the immediate solution is to have a private `std::vector<float>` member and implement your `Database` operations by forwarding the calls to the member vector.